# Debugging "Error Processing Payment" with PayPal Payments Standard

Tags: .net, debugging, paypal

I'm working to integrate PayPal Payments Standard with my custom .NET cart, and it's been an absolutely excruciating process, as their documentation is so scattershot and examples incomplete.

I'm using their API to generate encrypted buttons to upload my cart to them.  This is successful.  However, when I click the "pay now" button, all I get is:

> Error Processing Payment
>
> Your payment can't be processed. Please contact the merchant directly.

This is useless as it does not give me any detail as to why.  I have searched, in the PayPal dashboard, for a way to see transaction errors so that I may debug them.  I have found nothing.

What I would like to know is, simply, **how I do I debug this?  Where can I find any further information or error codes that tells me why this failed?  Is there anything in the PayPal dashboard that shows failed Payment attempts like this?**

For example, Amazon (which I have integrated with, and was a breeze), provides a console that shows all attempted and failed interactions for every API call.   Does PayPal have anything similar?  Or is it totally opaque?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is happening on the Paypal site, there's no console I know of. If that is the case I would open a ticket with [Paypal MTS](https://ppmts.custhelp.com/) and let them look at your button.

Comment: You're right; this was the only way to get information about what's happening on their side.  As a result, I gave up on their .NET API entirely and just wrote my own checkout, which took a fraction of the time.